# Validate URL with Regex and java.net.URL

Tags: java, strings, regex, validation, url

I'm writing a URL validator. Firstly, it checks for special characters in the input. Secondly, it adds 'http://' and checks for validity.

```java
    /* Returns true if url is valid */
    private static boolean isValidURL(String url) {
        boolean containsSpecialCharacters = specialCharactersExists(url);
        if ( !containsSpecialCharacters ) {
            /* Try creating a valid URL */
            try {
                new URL(String.format("%s%s", "http://", url)).toURI();
                return true;
            } catch (Exception e) {
                /* Not a valid URL */
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    /* Returns true if url contains special characters */
    private static boolean specialCharactersExists(String input) {
        Pattern regex = Pattern.compile("[^A-Za-z0-9.-]");
        Matcher matcher = regex.matcher(input);
        return matcher.find();
    }
```

This serves my purpose. I'm seeking advice on how to improve the code (especially the Regex part)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Welcome to Code Review!

**Bad naming**

The method doesn't actually check that a URL is valid, as it allows values that are not URLs. Thus it should not be named as "isValidURL". It should be `isValidAddress` or similar, but not URL. URLs have a [very well defined syntax](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/URL#Syntax).

**Unnecessary variables**

There is no need to store the return value of `specialCharactersExists(url)` to a variable. It only adds an unnecessary large if-statement. Instead, check the value and exit early. Also, the characters you check are not special, they're "illegal" or "invalid" in your implementation so change name to reflect that:

```
    if (illegalCharactersExist(url)) {
        return false;
    }
```

**Missing final**

Variables that are not supposed to change should be marked as `final`. If you decide to keep the containsSpecialCharacters variable, it should be marked as final (and named as decribed above).

```
final boolean containsIllegalCharacters = illegalCharactersExist(url);
```

**Reuse Pattern**

The Pattern class is [thread safe](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html). You should compile the pattern once into a static variable and reuse it in the matcher. Also, regex is not a good name. It tells what the variable is, not what it's purpose is. Naming should always reflect purpose.

```
    private static final Pattern ILLEGAL_CHAR_PATTERN = Pattern.compile("[^A-Za-z0-9.-]");
```